# Removing duplicate rows in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have three `GridView` that for some  reason has first duplicate data for the first three column> its not an error because thats how i want it to be.

I want the grid to leave blank where duplicate in the above two columns `Client Name` and `Branch` . I loop through my cells and set them to empty on `Databound` as below.

```
protected void gvList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string oldValue = string.Empty;
    string newValue = string.Empty;
    //  for (int count = 0; count < gvList.Rows.Count; count++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < gvList.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            oldValue = gvList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text;
            if (oldValue == newValue)
            {
                gvList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text = string.Empty;
            }
            newValue = oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

After running i get the result below. The grid do what i want to for a row and omit teh row proceeding it. I am confused. Please better alternative would be appreciated.

My second question is , i have another grid also that duplicate few rows. I applied the same method and `Dispose()` where duplicate but nothing change. I use

```
gridview.rows[].cells.clear/disposed()`
```

My girdview is as below.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvList_sorting" 
                   DataKeyNames="contactID" OnPageIndexChanging="gvList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvList_RowCancelingEdit" 
                   OnRowDeleting="gvList_RowDeleting"  OnRowEditing="gvList_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvList_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="gvList_RowDataBound"
               EnableModelValidation="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True">


                       <Columns> 


                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cname" HeaderText="Client Name" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="cname"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="bname" HeaderText="Branch" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="bname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Contact " SortExpression="name" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type " SortExpression="type" ReadOnly="true" />
                                  <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description " SortExpression="description" ReadOnly="true" />



                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                                 <asp:TemplateField>
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:linkbutton id="ContactlnkDelete" runat="server" text="Delete" causesvalidation="false" commandname="Delete" commandargument="ID">
                                            </asp:linkbutton>


                                            <cc1:modalpopupextender id="lnkDelete_ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" cancelcontrolid="ButtonDeleteCancel" okcontrolid="ButtonDeleleOkay" 
                                                targetcontrolid="ContactlnkDelete" popupcontrolid="DivDeleteConfirmation" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
                                           </cc1:modalpopupextender>
                                            <cc1:confirmbuttonextender id="lnkDelete_ConfirmButtonExtender2" runat="server" targetcontrolid="ContactlnkDelete" enabled="True" 
                                                    displaymodalpopupid="lnkDelete_ModalPopupExtender2">
                                           </cc1:confirmbuttonextender>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                               </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>


                       <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                       <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                       <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                       <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
               </asp:GridView>
```

but it also failed. Please, i need your assistance.

Comment: YAh sure. See the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use **DataBound** instead of **RowDataBound** like following:

```
protected void gvList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string oldValue = string.Empty;
    string newValue = string.Empty;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < gvList.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            oldValue = gvList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text;
            if (oldValue == newValue)
            {
                gvList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text = string.Empty;
            }
            newValue = oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

if you want delete rows:

Replace:

```
gvList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text = string.Empty;
```

with:

```
gvList.Rows[count].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Hi, It seems to work for me as well. Is there any way i can delete the row instead to setting the text to empty?

Comment: Thanks man..Really appreciate it LOL. I was trying `gvList.Rows[count].Cells.Disposed`. LOL it didnt do the job though. Thank you man..

Comment: Yah it still does Paging. May be because it's invisible only but recognized by the grid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38160/discussion-between-nuru-salihu-and-samiey-mehdi)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the same value to newValue and OldValue, and "must use Page_Load event insead of RowDataBound" (Thanks to Fer for pointing out what I missed.)

Try this:

```
 for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < gvList.Rows.Count; row++)
        {       

            if(gvList.Rows[row].Cells[column].Text != "")
                oldValue = gvList.Rows[row].Cells[column].Text;

            if (oldValue == newValue)
            {
                gvList.Rows[row].Cells[column].Text = string.Empty;
            }       

            if(row+1 < gvList.Rows.Count)
             newValue = gvList.Rows[row+1].Cells[column].Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Nuru Salihu this is right but he must use Page_Load event insead of RowDataBound.

Comment: BUt my Gridload on button click not onpageload. Also when i run the above changes i get the error On `newValue = gvList.Rows[row+1].Cells[column].Text` "Out of bound"

Comment: Thanks @NuruSalihu. I have edited the check before assigning to newValue inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> In the code above I used a 'for' cycle where the line in position 'i' compares with all the lines in 'j' position, and if there is a match the line in position 'i' is eliminated in order to avoid duplicate data

```
   void delete_Duplicate_data()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Gv.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < Gv.RowCount; j++)
            {
               if (Gv.Rows[i].Cells[gID.Name].Value.ToString() == Gv.Rows[j].Cells[gID.Name].Value.ToString())
                {
                     Gv.Rows.Remove(Gv.Rows[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are allowed but discouraged. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what is going on here so that in the future this may be more helpful to those trying to understand. Also, SO expects answers in English.

Comment: ohh sorry me.
in the code above I used a 'for' cycle where the line in position 'i' compares with all the lines in 'j' position, and if there is a match the line in position 'i' is eliminated in order to avoid duplicate data

Comment: Please edit the answer to include that text rather than in the comments : )